# How do I get BitBucket.org commits to trigger TeamCity builds?

Tags: teamcity, bitbucket, webhooks

How does one configure webhooks in BitBucket.org to trigger TeamCity builds?

Answer (score 6):

Use the TeamCity REST API:

1. Create a user on your TeamCity server with `Run build` permission
2. Create a new webhook on BitBucket to the prepared URL

   ```
   http://username:password@teamcity.server.address/httpAuth/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=vcsRoot:(type:jetbrains.git,count:99999),property:(name:url,value:bitbucket.org/bitbucketusername/repo.git,matchType:contains),count:99999
   ```

   - Replace `username`,`password` with the user you just created
   - Replace `teamcity.server.address`, `bitbucketusername` and `repo` with your repo values,

See docs for more information:

- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-VCSrootinstancelocator
- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP

Comment: Your answer is a bit too complicated as it mentions `count:99999` twice, and matches VCS root by a part of URL path